# Consume events from EventHub In Azure Databricks using pySpark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-eventhub, databricks

I could see spark connectors & guidelines  for consuming events from Event Hub using Scala in Azure Databricks.

**But, How can we consume events in event Hub from azure databricks using pySpark?**

any suggestions/documentation details would help. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is the snippet for reading events from event hub from pyspark on azure data-bricks.

```
// With an entity path 
val with = "Endpoint=sb://SAMPLE;SharedAccessKeyName=KEY_NAME;SharedAccessKey=KEY;EntityPath=EVENTHUB_NAME"


# Source with default settings
connectionString = "Valid EventHubs connection string."
ehConf = {
  'eventhubs.connectionString' : connectionString
}

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()

readInStreamBody = df.withColumn("body", df["body"].cast("string"))
display(readInStreamBody)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is slight modification that is required if you are using spark version **2.4.5** or greater and version of the Azure event Hub Connector **2.3.15** or above

For **2.3.15** version and above, the configuration dictionary requires that connection string be encrypted, So you need to pass it as shown in the code snippet below.

```
connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://SAMPLE;SharedAccessKeyName=KEY_NAME;SharedAccessKey=KEY;EntityPath=EVENTHUB_NAME"
ehConf = {}
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()

readInStreamBody = df.withColumn("body", df["body"].cast("string"))
display(readInStreamBody)
```